# Can Yolo-V3 trained model be converted to TensorFlow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, yolo

I have trained my model of doors in yolo-v3 but now I need it in TensorFlow-Lite. But, I am facing a problem, that is, if I want to train my model for tensorflow, I need annotation file in "*.csv" or "*.xml" but the ones I have are "*.txt". I did found a software to create annotation files manually from drawing rectangles in pictures but I can not do that for thousands of images due to time shortage.
Can anyone guide me how to handle such situation?

I have followed the following link but the resulted model did not work.
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/yolov3-to-tensorflow-lite-conversion-4602cec5c239

Comment: Do you want to convert your yolo model into tensorflow (tf) ? or you don't have annotation files. If you don't have then there is no shortcut , you have to mannually annotate it.
But you have trained your model then it can convert easily.
Comment to know how to convert.

Answer (score 0):

i think it will be good to train tensorflow implementation on your data , then converting tensrflow model to tflite should be easy
here is yolov3 in tf : https://github.com/YunYang1994/tensorflow-yolov3
then use official tensorflow codes to convert to tflite : https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert